# How to avoid displaying a field when hovering over feature in QGIS cloud?

Tags: qgis, qgis-cloud

I have uploaded data for a presentation into the QGIS cloud and noticed that in the browser when I hover over it (info button selected because I want to click on a certain feature)[image], a field and its value is being shown. I don't want that and tried to change the display options in the layer properties but it doesn't go away. This is annoying when zoomed out because if there are many features at one location, all!! their values are listed. How can I get rid of this?

[image]

Comment: http://blog.sourcepole.ch/2015/11/18/image-tooltip-with-qgis-cloud/ comments into more detail try support@qgiscloud.com